# PL/SQL call from JDBC resulting in "SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900"

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, plsql

I'm trying to use the following code to run a PL/SQL statement on my database server.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jdbcURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.22.88.9:1521/xavier.i.com";

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String user = "bigdb";
        String password = "fakepassword";
        String result = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, user, password);

            result = runStatement(conn,
              "{begin ANALYZE TABLE BIGDB.scr_fct_exact_access
              ESTIMATE STATISTICS; end}");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String runStatement(Connection con, String statement)
      throws Exception {
        PreparedStatement cstmt = con.prepareStatement(statement);
        cstmt.execute(); // this is line 58
        cstmt.close();

        return count;
    }
}
```

On running the code, I get the following exception:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1010)Time : -1307015416548
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3677)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1374)
>           at Main.prepareStatement(Main.java:58)
>           at Main.main(Main.java:29)

What is going wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ANALYZE TABLE` is a DDL (data definition language) statement. It's not valid within a BEGIN/END block in PL/SQL. If you wanted to execute it in PL/SQL, you'd need to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

To run the statement from JDBC, just create a `Statement` instance and use `executeUpdate`:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("ANALYZE TABLE BIGDB.scr_fct_exact_access ESTIMATE STATISTICS");
stmt.close();
```

But a even better idea is to use the `DBMS_STATS` package to analyze your tables. Then you can use your approach with BEGIN/END.

Comment: @Codo...can you please tell me if I can get the results of the above query. Like a ResultSet or something.

Comment: ANALYZE TABLE isn't a query. It has no result. Either it runs okay or it fails. If it fails, an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CallableStatement` instead of `PreparedStatement` to [run statements with the PL/SQL block syntax from JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28765/addfunc.htm#CIHDGFFB).

However, as Codo has stated in the other answer, [ANALYZE TABLE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4005.htm) isn't exactly callable from PL/SQL. It is a SQL command, and hence cannot be executed in a PL/SQL block. And as rightly suggested, `DBMS_STATS` ought to be used. This is also stated in the documentation of the ANALYZE command:

> **Note:**
>
> For the collection of most
>   statistics, use the DBMS_STATS
>   package, which lets you collect
>   statistics in parallel, collect global
>   statistics for partitioned objects,
>   and fine tune your statistics
>   collection in other ways. See Oracle
>   Database PL/SQL Packages and Types
>   Reference for more information on the
>   DBMS_STATS package. Use the ANALYZE
>   statement (rather than DBMS_STATS) for
>   statistics collection not related to
>   the cost-based optimizer:
>
> - To use the VALIDATE or LIST CHAINED
>     ROWS clauses
> - To collect information on freelist
>     blocks

If you really want to avoid using `DBMS_STATS` (and honestly, I wouldn't see a good reason to avoid it), use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or `DBMS_SQL` to execute the `ANALYZE TABLE` command.